# Can't Reset Github From SSH to HTTPS on Visual Studio Code Git Bash

Tags: git, github

I am trying to use HTTPS instead of SSH on github because LFS upload keeps failing.

So I added a 17KB png file to my project.

I have VS code + git bash for terminal installed on Windows.

I do

```
git add .
git commit
git push
```

When I do `git commit` the following shows:

```
$ git commit
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
Enumerating objects: 64608, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), done.
Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Checking connectivity: 93761, done.
warning: There are too many unreachable loose objects; run 'git prune' to remove them.
[master 36bb174cb] added lfs
 1 file changed, 3 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/docs/assets/ClassDiagrams/Architecture.png
```

Ok so I do git push

It gets stuck here:

```
$ git push
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/account/.ssh/id_rsa':
Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/1), 0 B | 0 B/s
```

Thereafter it gives me a failed message

```
$ git push
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/account/.ssh/id_rsa':
batch request: git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).: exit status 255
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://github.com/mygithubaccount/restart.git'
```

So I try to change SSH to HTTPS on github it doesn't seem to work

I put in command line:

```
$ git config --global url."https://github.com/"
```

insteadOf `git@github.com:`

And github continues to use SSH.

I am curious if the fact that I use SSH prevents me from uploading LFS files. I just want these files uploaded. A single png file is only 17kb. I try to upload one at a time and it still doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your remote is in form of SSH and not in HTTPS. You need to convert that first.

To check if the remote is in SSH, type `git remote -v` the remote links list will appear. If it's in form of git@github.com then you can change your remote to HTTPS...

1. Type `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git`
2. Again type `git remote -v`

So next time, you'd see that instead of SSH, HTTPS remote will be there and you're now good to go

Comment: I put git remote -v and it showed that git remote -v origin was set to ssh for fetch and push so I followed the instructions above and typed git remote -v and I still see SSH. What do I do now?

Comment: OK uh.... Then do this... `git remote remove origin` (instead of origin if you have upstream please replace origin) then type `git remote add origin <URL of git>` then try git git fetch